# Get tokenResponse.Token in OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync event

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get Access Token retrieved in OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync using  tokenResponse.Token in event OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync. Can anyone lead me to the right way?

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/55de4341a44767578283ecb480bfb639e215a66b/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.cs
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: I have already checked this link. What I need is to get access token in  this method: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/55de4341a44767578283ecb480bfb639e215a66b/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.cs#:~:text=override%20Task%3CMessagingExtensionResponse%3E-,OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync,-(ITurnContext%3CIInvokeActivity%3E%20turnContext

Comment: As a workaround for now, I am passing token along with variable defined in line number 208 and accessing it back on line number 240. But it doesnt seems to me a right way. I want to get access token using TurnContext or something standard way.

Comment: You get the access token using Graph API also.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#getting-an-access-token

Comment: No, I don't need authentication Token for Graph api but a third party Identity provider. The connection is defined in Bot Configuration page for Generic OAuth.

Comment: You can call under this method OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync 
var tokenResponse = await GetTokenResponse(turnContext, state, cancellationToken);
you get the Token .
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.cs

Comment: Hi Sayali, No this way is not possible, I already tested that. GetTokenResponse whiich you are referring is a function created by the Team Scaffolding. The state which you are passing requires to have a magic code, this is how you get it in OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync event :  if (int.TryParse(state, out var parsed))
                {
                    magicCode = parsed.ToString();
                }

Comment: But in OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync, state is JObject which doesnt have any magic code property. So it fails in GetTokenResponse method.

Comment: instead of taking out the magic code from state, try passing random integer.